# how to clone private gitlab repo in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to do a git clone of a private gitlab repo inside a shell script in Jenkinsfile and i have just been unable to find a way. I mean this is a simple git clone and i can't believe i have to come here to seek help with such simple task. It is unfortunate that gitlab support always comes with extra cost compared to github.

Another unfortunate thing is i have searched the whole internet and can't find a solution to my problem. 
I have the Gitlab plugin and also tried to use the gitlab api token, but there is no support for gitlab api token in jenkins..no way to use it with withcrdentials or any other thing

I have also tried regular withcredentials with username and password and that does not work either

also tried http and git repo url
the http one says not found and the git or ssh one gives host key errors

what i have tried

```
   steps {
     git url: 'https://gitlab.example.com/user/example_repo.git', branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'my-gitlab-repo-creds'
   }
```

got this error

> git: 'url:' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
>
> Did you mean this?    prune

other errors from other trials and errors

> Cloning into 'example_repo'...
>   Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

and

> Cloning into 'example_repo'... fatal: could not read Username for
>   'https://gitlab.example.com': No such device or address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to use the `checkout` pipeline step instead of the `git` one.

```
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: '*/master' ]],
                extensions: scm.extensions,
                userRemoteConfigs: [[
                    url: 'https://gitlab.example.com/user/example_repo.git',
                    credentialsId: 'my-gitlab-repo-creds'
                ]]
            ])
```

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/

Comment: where in the stage block is this supposed to be? inside the sh shell block or where?

Comment: it is supposed to be right before the sh step, in place of the git step. So it looks like pipeline -> stage -> steps -> checkout